# React Hook update input field: text is invisible until user press enter

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React Hooks in my React-native application but I have a problem.

When I was using the class component with the constructor it was working fine but now when the user select the text input and start inputting something, the text appears only when the user press 'enter'. To be more clear: the user press "t" and the input is still empty, then "e", then "s" then "t", the input is still empty. When the user presses the enter button on the keyboard, the "test" appears all at once. Here's the code:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState('')

return(
  <TextInput
    type="text"
    placeholder="insert your filter"
    onChange={(event) => setFilter(event.target.value)}
    value={filter}
  />
)
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: link to a sandbox with the entire component: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-fermi-kidjx)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code, can you provide the rest of the component in a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

React Native `TextInput` accepts the prop `onChangeText`

This is an example from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function UselessTextInput() {   const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Placeholder');

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />   ); }
```

Comment: You are right, it solved a bug, when the input behave as described even with `onChangeText`...I guess there's some other problem somewhere else :(

Comment: I am happy it solved the bug, but the `onChange ` should work as well...

Answer (score 0):

pass wrong value to setFilter.  Onchange in textinput callback that is called when the text input's text changes. This will be called with { nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function TextInputWrapper() {
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState('')
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChange={event => setFilter(event.nativeEvent.text)}
      value={filter}
    />);
}
```

for more see documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange). you can also use [onChangeText](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onChangeText) props which is wrapper on [onChange](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange)